# Global Application Configuration for Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, rest, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I was just looking through the documentation of Microsoft Graph. I was wondering if I could store global configuration of the app somewhere? I found the "open extension" specification but from what I can see its user specific.

I would like to store an internal navigation link map. Admins should be able to change this JSON array.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No such API now, you need to **store/maintain** the global configuration by **your own api/service**.

If you expect MS Graph can support this feature too, you need to submit an feature request by the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).